# list the hard disk details without root user

Tags: command-line, disk

want to know how do the normal users know the hard disk details

And i already tried with lshw and some of the following

I need to know hard disk details from the normal user

Comment: `lshw` will only show the disk access if you are part of the `disk` group or have sudo access.  Run `groups` to show what you are part of.  Beyond that, all applications that I have tried or know about require sudo / administrative access to either install or run to show the drive information.

Comment: It won't work without the help of super user it seems is right @Terrance..

Answer (score 0):

As non sudo/root user. -z is for filtering, -y80 is to make output narrower:

```
inxi -dzxxxy80
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.98 TiB used: 602.87 GiB (29.7%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Intel model: SSDSC2BW180A4 size: 167.68 GiB 
  speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> rev: DC32 scheme: MBR 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD1003FZEX-00MK2A0 
  size: 931.51 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s rotation: 7200 rpm serial: <filter> 
  rev: 1A01 temp: 31 C scheme: GPT 
  ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Western Digital model: WD1001FALS-00E8B0 
  size: 931.51 GiB speed: 3.0 Gb/s rotation: 7200 rpm serial: <filter> 
  rev: 0K05 temp: 37 C scheme: GPT 
  Optical-1: /dev/sr0 vendor: HL-DT-ST model: DVDRAM GH20LS10 rev: FL00 
  dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd,dvdrw 
  Features: speed: 48 multisession: yes audio: yes dvd: yes 
  rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r,dvd-ram state: running
```

It actually offers even more data but that version isn't in Ubuntu yet. I've set hddtemp to be able to be run as user, not root, normally you would not see temp data unless root.